# Rails - stack level too deep for geocoding method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to implement a geocoding feature in my app but I am getting a "stack level too deep" error for the following method in the model I want to geocode:

**From the gem README:**
If your model has street, city, state, and country attributes you might do something like this:

```
geocoded_by :address

def address
  [street, city, state, country].compact.join(', ')
end
```

I did the same thing for my model without the state and country as my model has 'street' and 'city' attributes.

Why am I getting this infinite loop (I'm guessing that is why) for this method?

---

The gem is: https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder

You can see they have the same example I laid out above.

Comment: What is the name of the gem and could you provide a link to the documentation?

Comment: Please post the stack trace

Comment: There's nothing here that would cause a recursive loop. Can you post more of your model ?

Comment: 1. post a stacktrace 2. is there another method or property called "address" in your model? 3. how are you invoking the geocoder?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
def address
    "#{street}, #{city}, #{state}, #{country}"
end
```